# Here is my code for checking if user is exist or not with email address but this code does not working

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my code for checking if user is exist or not with email address but this code does not working.

Please help me through this. Any suggestion how can i check if user already in database with help of email.

```php
<? php 
$con = m ysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user_regi");
$sql = m ysqli_select_db($con, 'user_regi');

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error($con));
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email = $ _POST['email'];
  $query = m ysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM  u_reg WHERE u_mail='$email'");

  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "User Already Exist";
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You want to take a look at the advantages of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: What does "this code does not working" actually mean? Do you get an error? Which? Does the code "crash"? How? Don't you get a row back from the database? What is the content of database and `$email`?

Comment: Also you can simply check it via 1 ie, `SELECT 1 FROM  u_reg WHERE u_mail='$email'` No need to select `*`

Comment: Most likely your query simply does not deliver any result, but an error. You never check for an error but blindly expect a valid query result. Please add error detection and handling to the code. Also start looking at the http servers error log file to see what the issue here is.

Comment: @arkascha i want check duplicate entries in email column if exist then it should say user is already exist .

Comment: @arkascha yes even i tried try and catch but it didnt work also ...!! I added duplicate email address and it was accepted. What should i do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with exception handling (`try ... catch...`), since no exceptions are thrown. I mentioned error handling. Please start reading the documentation for phps mysqli extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @arkascha is there any way you can help me through this?

Comment: What question do you have? The examples in the documentation clearly show how to detect errors: `mysqli_query()` returns `false` in case of an error with the query. So check what `$query` contains... This is clearly stated here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php under "Return Values"... To read the actual error message use `mysqli_error()` afterwards... And as said above: take a look into your error log file.

Comment: You might find [the mysqli OO interface](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) better to work with than the functional one.